# How do I dynamically allocate memory for specific elements in a matrix?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
1 2 0 0 0
0 2 3 0 0
0 0 4 5 0
0 0 0 5 6
0 0 0 0 7
```

I am trying to allocate a matrix in this format, but the elements that are equal to 0 shouldn't be dynamically allocated. And this allocation needs to be efficient.

Comment: Use a null pointer for the elements you haven't allocated.

Comment: It will need to be an array of array of pointers.

Comment: Is there a specific representation of the matrix you're using? A sparse matrix might be superior

Comment: @Daniel what's a sparse matrix?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) is your friend

Comment: @Daniel the teacher called this a bidiagonal matrix

Comment: @Barmar Would this matrix be considered a band matrix?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it. Is your matrix always going to be like this?

Comment: it's an nxn matrix and it will depend on n and I haven't figured the pattern yet.

Comment: For a bidiagonal matrix of size n, you only need 2n−1 elements. However, then you need special code to work with the matrix representation—code that returns an element given its indices, or code that multiplies a bidiagonal-represented matrix with a dense (regular) matrix, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of one possible solution to get you started. Other methods are possible. This code is not tested.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef float T;

//  Attempt to allocate space for a bidiagonal matrix of size n-by-n.
T *MallocBidiagonalMatrix(size_t n) { return malloc((2*n-1) * sizeof(T)); }

//  Free a bidiagonal matrix.
void FreeBidiagonalMatrix(T *p) { free(p); }

//  Return a reference to element [r, c] of bidiagonal matrix p of size n-by-n.
T *BidiagonalMatrixElement(size_t n, T *p, size_t r, size_t c)
{
    static T Zero = 0;

    //  The diagonal elements are stored from p[0] to p[n-1].
    if (r == c)
        return p+r;

    //  The existing off-diagonal elements are stored from p[n] to p[2*n-2].
    if (r == c-1)
        return p+n+r;

    /*  For non-existing (zero) elements, return a reference to zero.  (Callers
        are expected not to write to this address.  If they do, the behavior is
        not defined.)
    */
    else
        return &Zero;
}

/*  Show how a bidiagonal matrix previously allocated with
    MallocBidiagonalMatrix might be initialized.
*/
void InitializeBidiagonalMatrix(size_t n, T *p)
{
    //  Initialize the diagonal elements.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        *BidiagonalMatrixElement(n, p, i, i) = rand();

    //  Initialize the off-diagonal elements.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n-1; ++i)
        *BidiagonalMatrixElement(n, p, i, i+1) = rand();
}

/*  Show how a bidiagonal matrix might be used in arithmetic by demonstrating
    a simple matrix addition.  The n-by-n bidiagonal matrix p is added to
    n-by-n matrix q.
*/
void AddBidiagonalMatrixToDenseMatrix(size_t n, T *p, T (*q)[n])
{
    for (size_t r = 0; r < n; ++r)
        for (size_t c = 0; c < n; ++c)
            q[r][c] += *BidiagonalMatrixElement(n, p, r, c);
}
```

Note that `AddBidiagonalMatrixToDenseMatrix` could be optimized to process just the stored elements. However, the given implementation demonstrates how an algorithm oblivious to which elements are actually stored could operate.

Comment: Nice answer. Code could use `else
        return &Zero;` --> `else { Zero = 0;  return &Zero;}` to mitigate some "behavior is
        not defined" cases.

Comment: how is the sum between the pointer p and the integer r possible?

Comment: @Diana: Per clause 6.5.6, paragraph 8, of the C 2018 standard, if a pointer `p` points to element *i* of an array and `n` is an expression of integer type, then `p+n` points to element *i* + `n` of the array (provided such an element is in the array or is one past the end of the array—if it would be out of bounds, the behavior is not defined).

Comment: @chux: Sometimes I think undefined behavior should be exacerbated, rather than mitigated, to increase the probability it is discovered early.

Comment: @EricPostpischil How about `else { if (Zero) exit(EXIT_FAILURE); return &Zero;}` to punish bad boy code? ;-)

Comment: @chux: Sure. You could even check on every execution of the routine, not just when a zero element is requested. And conditionalize it on the `DEBUG` preprocessor identifier, so it is present in development versions of the program and not deployment versions.